# Composer/Laravel Fatal Error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I added this to my composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Claremontdesign\\Cdbase\\": "packages/Claremontdesign/cdbase/src",
        "Claremontdesign\\Narbase\\": "packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src",
        "Claremontdesign\\Nhr\\": "packages/Claremontdesign/nhr/src"
    },
   "files": [
        "packages/Claremontdesign/cdbase/src/Helpers/helpers.php",
        "packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src/Helpers/helpers.php",
        "packages/Claremontdesign/nhr/src/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

then, I ran `composer update` from the command line, and it gave me this error:

> symfony component debug exception fatalerrorexception class "Claremontdesign\Cdbase\ServiceProvider" not found

Has anyone else encountered this?

Also, I added a service provider in add.php

```
Claremontdesign\Cdbase\ServiceProvider::class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try running just `composer dump`? `composer update` runs some scripts before it actually runs - for example `php artisan clear-compiled`. When artisan runs, it'll probably fail because it tries to register the serviceprovider which isn't autoloaded yet. `composer dump` only generates the autoload files, which is what you need in this case.

Comment: thanks, I did composer dumpautoload, it got me out of the problem.. but I'm having another error though.

Comment: Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\nhr\nhr/packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src/Helpers/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\nhr\nhr\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\nhr\nhr/packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src/Helpers/helpers.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\nhr\nhr\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54

Comment: Can you verify that `D:\xampp\htdocs\nhr\nhr/packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src/Helpers/helpers.ph‌p` does actually exist? (Don't mind the alternating directory separators for now)

Comment: If that does exist, try swapping all your directory separators with a backslash since you're on a windows system :) So that `"packages/Claremontdesign/cdbase/src/"` becomes `"packages\Claremontdesign\cdbase\src\"`

Comment: Seems, like I needed to remove what wasn't there. my bad -.-

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing one more slash after every src folder

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Claremontdesign\\Cdbase\\": "packages/Claremontdesign/cdbase/src/",
        "Claremontdesign\\Narbase\\": "packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src/",
        "Claremontdesign\\Nhr\\": "packages/Claremontdesign/nhr/src/"
    },
   "files": [
        "packages/Claremontdesign/cdbase/src/Helpers/helpers.php",
        "packages/Claremontdesign/narbase/src/Helpers/helpers.php",
        "packages/Claremontdesign/nhr/src/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: after using slash you need to run "composer dump-autoload" from terminal.